# How to run two or more sql query at the same time?

Tags: c#, mysql, parallel-processing, delegates, backgroundworker

I want to run more query at the really same time in different thread. I am using backgroundworkers to solve this problem! My question is: Is there better way to delegate UI element or is it correct as i did it?

```
    private void mainform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (bscan_backgroundworker.IsBusy == false)
        {
            bscan_backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    if (bscan2_backgroundworker.IsBusy == false)
        {
            bscan2_backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    }

    private void bscan_backgroundworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bscan();

    }

    private void bscan2_backgroundworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bscan2();

    }

    private void bscan()
    {  

     string query = "Select * from table_name";
     MySqlConnection mysqlconn_to_db = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
        try
        {
            mysqlconn_to_db.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn_to_db))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(datatable);


                    if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                        {
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
                            dataGridView1.Refresh();
                            label2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(label1.Text)].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
                        dataGridView1.Refresh();                           
                        label2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(label1.Text)].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    }


                adapter.Dispose();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messagebox(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

bscan2() method is nearly the same as bscan() with different query and different datagridview. Is there more efficient way to do it, or its ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BackgroundWorker` solution isn't necessarily a bad one, but there are new and improved ways to handle asynchronous programming in C#. It's highly recommended that you look into [`async` and `await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async). That may not apply quite so directly to what you're trying to accomplish in this case since you don't seem to want to wait for one method to complete, so it's also recommended that you look into the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), and particularly [`Task.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_). There's even something called [Parallel LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq) that is specifically meant for handling asynchronous queries.